# Dynamic loading kivy label

Tags: kivy

When I define a variable a, how to dynamically update the value of label when the value of a changes? What I want to do is an app to read the data collected from raspberry pie, but I can't dynamically display the value of label now

```
<StackLayoutExample>:
    rows:8
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            font_name:"font/CHN.ttf"
            font_size: "28dp"
            text:"model"
        ToggleButton:
            font_name:"font/CHN.ttf"
            font_size: "28dp"
            on_state:root.on_toggle_button_state(self)
            text:"Auto"

    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            font_name:"font/CHN.ttf"
            font_size: "24dp"
            text:"temperature"
        Label:
            font_name:"font/CHN.ttf"
            font_size: "28dp"
            text:str(root.temperature)
        Label:
            font_name:"font/CHN.ttf"
            font_size: "24dp"
            text:"humidity"
        Label:
            font_name:"font/CHN.ttf"
            font_size: "28dp"
            text:str(root.humidity)
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.